# Copy and Cascade insert using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

***Given data structure:***

I have the following table **My_List**, where *Sup_ID* is Primary Key

**My_List**

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| Sup_ID | Sup_Name |  Sup_Code |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | AA       |        23 |
|      2 | BB       |        87 |
|      3 | CC       |        90 |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

And the following table **_MyList_details**, where *Buy_ID* is Primary Key and *Sup_ID* is Foreign Key points at *My_List.Sup_ID*

**My_List_details**

```
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
| Buy_ID | Sup_ID | Sup_Detail | Max_Amount | Min_Amount |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
|     23 |      1 | AAA        |          1 |         10 |
|     33 |      2 | BBB        |         11 |         20 |
|     43 |      3 | CCC        |         21 |         30 |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Finally, I have the table **My_Sequence** as follow:

**My_Sequence**

```
+-----+------+
| Seq | Name |
+-----+------+
|   4 | x    |
|   5 | y    |
|   6 | z    |
+-----+------+
```

**---------------------------------------------------**

***Objectives***

Write PL/SQL script to:

1. Using a cursor, I need to copy *My_List* records and re-insert it with the new *Sup_ID* copied from *My_Sequence.Seq*.
2. I need to copy *My_List_details* records and re-insert them with the new *Sup_ID* foreign key.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

***Expected Outcome***

**My_List**

```
+--------+----------+----------+
| Sup_ID | Sub_Name | Sub_Code |
+--------+----------+----------+
|      1 | AA       |       23 |
|      2 | BB       |       87 |
|      3 | CC       |       90 |
|      4 | AA       |       23 |
|      5 | BB       |       87 |
|      6 | CC       |       90 |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

**My_List_details**

```
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
| Buy_ID | Sup_ID | Sub_Detail | Max_Amount | Min_Amount |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
|     23 |      1 | AAA        |          1 |         10 |
|     33 |      2 | BBB        |         11 |         20 |
|     43 |      3 | CCC        |         21 |         30 |
|     53 |      4 | AAA        |          1 |         10 |
|     63 |      5 | BBB        |         11 |         20 |
|     73 |      6 | CCC        |         21 |         30 |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
```

What I have started with is the following:

```
DECLARE
  NEW_Sup_ID Sup_ID%type := Seq;
  c_Sup_Name Sup_Name%type;
  c_Sup_Code Sup_Code%type;
  c_Buy_ID Buy_ID%type;
  c_Sup_Detail Sup_Detail%type;
  c_Max_Amount Max_Amount%type
  c_My_Min_Amount Min_Amount%type

  CURSOR c_My_List
  IS
    SELECT * FROM My_List;
  CURSOR c_My_List_details
  IS
    SELECT * FROM My_List_details 
  BEGIN
    FETCH c_My_List INTO NEW_Sup_ID, c_Sup_Name, c_Sup_Code;
    INSERT INTO My_List;
    FETCH c_My_List_details INTO c_Buy_ID, NEW_Sup_ID, c_Sup_Detail, c_Max_Amount, c_Min_Amount
    INSERT INTO My_List_details 
  END;
/
```

Aside from the syntax errors, I do not see my script copy row by row and insert them to both tables accordingly. Further, the number of *My_Sequence* records is bigger than the number of *My_List* records. So what I need is, if *My_List* records are 50, I need the script to copy the first 50 *Seq* from *My_Sequence*.

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

***Question***

How to achieve this result? I have searched and found [Tom Kyte](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html) for cascade update but I am not sure if I do need to use this package, I am a bit beginner in PL/SQL and it is a bit complicated for me to utilize such a comprehensive package. Further, it's for cascade update and my case is about re-insert. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Why is it an objective that you should use a cursor?

Comment: also - what is the rule that identifies which of the sequence records should be used?

Comment: @HughJones The objective is write PL/SQL to achieve the result, I assumed myself (with my limited knowledge in the area) that I will need a cursor.

Comment: @HughJones The rule is copy them in sequence, 4 -> 1, 5-> 2, 6 -> 3

Comment: You only use cursors when all else fails.

Comment: ok, so is it reasonable to say `OLDVAL + 3` ?

Comment: @HughJones Unfortunately no, this is simple example, the ID's are indeed big random numbers

Comment: So what is the rule ?

Comment: @HughJones The rule is the ID's order, first ID in Sequence table goes for the first record in List table and so forth

Comment: @HughJones No not all, your questions help to clarify mine. I appreciate that :)

Comment: @HughJones Yes was a typo, Thank you for pointing this out :)

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code you've written and the specific problems you're having. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis I have inserted my attempt. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Sql Statements will perform the task on the schema defined at [this SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5477).  Note that I have changed a couple of field and table names - because they clash with Oracle terms.  SqlFiddle seems to have some problems with my code, but it has been tested on another (amphibious) client which shall remain nameless.

The crucial point (As I said in my comments) is deriving a rule to map old sequence number to new.  The view `SEQUENCE_MAP` performs this task in the queries below.

You may be disappointed by my reply because it depends upon there being the exact same number of sequence records as `LIST/LIST_DETAILS`, and hence it can only be run once.  Your final PL/SQL can perform the necessary checks, I hope.

Hopefully it is a matter of refining the `sequence_map` logic to get you where you want to be.

Avoid using cursors; ideally when manipulating relational data you need to think in terms of sets of data rather than rows.  This is because if you use set-thinking Oracle can do its magic in optimising, parallelising and so-on.  Oracle is brilliant at scaling up - If a table is split over multiple disks, for example, it may process your request with data from the multiple disks simultaneously.  If you force it into a row-by-row, procedural logic you may find that the applications you write do not scale up well.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SEQUENCE_MAP AS ( 
    SELECT OLD_SEQ, NEW_SEQ FROM
    ( 
      ( SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, SUP_ID AS OLD_SEQ FROM
        (SELECT SUP_ID FROM LIST ORDER BY SUP_ID) ) O 
      JOIN
      ( SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, SUP_ID AS NEW_SEQ  FROM 
        (SELECT SEQ AS SUP_ID FROM SEQUENCE_TABLE ORDER BY SEQ) ) N
      ON N.RN = O.RN 
    ) 
  );  

INSERT INTO LIST
( 
 SELECT 
   NEW_SEQ, SUB_NAME, SUB_CODE  
 FROM 
  SEQUENCE_MAP  
  JOIN LIST L ON
    L.SUP_ID = SEQUENCE_MAP.OLD_SEQ 
);

INSERT INTO LIST_DETAILS
( 
 SELECT 
    BUY_ID, NEW_SEQ, SUB_DETAIL, MAX_FIELD, MIN_FIELD   
 FROM 
   SEQUENCE_MAP  
   JOIN LIST_DETAILS L ON
     L.SUP_ID = SEQUENCE_MAP.OLD_SEQ   
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure about Sequence_map logic. Don't you think using LOOP to insert record by record would be clearer and easier to understand?

Comment: A cursor might be easier to understand, and therefore perhaps quicker to write. For the reasons to which I have alluded cursors should only be used when all else fails.  Cursors in PL/SQL are a trap for the unwary; they are easy to conceive, procedural constructs that work well in only limited circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

I would do 2 inner loops, and search the next sequence to use.

I imagine the new buy_id is assigned via trigger using a sequence, or something equivalent, else you'll have to generate it in your code.

I have no Oracle database available to test it, so don't pay attention to syntax.

```
DECLARE
  NEW_Sup_ID Sup_ID%type := Seq;
  c_Sup_ID Sup_ID%type := Seq;
  c_Sup_Name Sup_Name%type;
  c_Sup_Code Sup_Code%type;
  c_Buy_ID Buy_ID%type;
  c_Sup_Detail Sup_Detail%type;
  c_Max_Amount Max_Amount%type;
  c_My_Min_Amount Min_Amount%type;
  CURSOR c_My_List
  IS
    SELECT * FROM My_List;
  CURSOR c_My_List_details
  IS
    SELECT * FROM My_List_details where sup_id=c_Sup_ID;
  BEGIN
    for c_My_List IN c_Sup_ID, c_Sup_Name, c_Sup_Code loop
    select min(seq) from My_sequence into NEW_Sup_ID;
    INSERT INTO My_List (sup_id,...) values (NEW_Sup_ID,...);
    for  c_My_List_details IN c_Buy_ID, NEW_Sup_ID, c_Sup_Detail, c_Max_Amount, c_Min_Amount loop
    INSERT INTO My_List_details (sup_id, ...) values (NEW_Sup_ID,...);
    end loop;
    deelte from  from My_sequence where seq= NEW_Sup_ID;
    end loop;
    commit;
  END;
/
```